# Как получить прикрепленный к электронному письму файл android retrofit?

Tags: android

У меня в приложении я работаю с сообщениями, которые либо мне приходят либо я отсылаю кому-то. Иногда в сообщениях есть прикрепленный файл, который нужно как-то загрузить на телефон. Для загрузки вложения я буду посылать на сервер запрос. Мне уже выдали апи. Вначале я создал в интерфейсе запрос:

```
@Headers({"Content-type:applica
Call<GetAttachment> getAttach (@Header("Autorization") String token,@Path("id") Integer id, @Path("attach_file_name") String file_name, @Query("type") int type, @Query("offset") int offset);
```

дальше я буду передавать название файла и `id` сообщения с которого я хочу скачать этот файл. Я пока-что не придумал что писать в классе `GetAttachment`, для начала я решил разместить кнопку под телом сообщения, что-бы если есть прикрепленный файл она делалась кликабельной. У меня есть класс `ViewMessage` который отвечает за вытаскивание из ответа сервера все данные по сообщению, тему, тело, отправителя и тд. В этот класс я так думаю мне нужно добавить функцию которая будет вытаскивать название прикрепленного файла, вот например как у меня выглядит прикрепленный файл в сообщении:

```
"attach": [["\udcd0\udc9d\udcd0\udcbe\udcd0\udcb2\udcd1\udc8b\udcd0\udcb9 \udcd1\udc82\udcd0\udcb5\udcd0\udcba\udcd1\udc81\udcd1\udc82\udcd0\udcbe\udcd0\udcb2\udcd1\udc8b\udcd0\udcb9 \udcd0\udcb4\udcd0\udcbe\udcd0\udcba\udcd1\udc83\udcd0\udcbc\udcd0\udcb5\udcd0\udcbd\udcd1\udc82 (2).txt", 0.4443359375]]
```

это я так вижу массив данных, название и размер файла, вот мне нужно как-то вытащить название файла. Я добавил переменную и метод в класс `ViewMessage`:

```
public class ViewMessage {

    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("body")
    @Expose
    private String body;
    @SerializedName("can_delete")
    @Expose
    private String canDelete;
    @SerializedName("can_reply")
    @Expose
    private String canReply;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("subject")
    @Expose
    private String subject;

    @SerializedName("attach")
    @Expose
    private String attach;

    public String getAttach() {
        return attach;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getCanDelete() {
        return canDelete;
    }

    public void setCanDelete(String canDelete) {
        this.canDelete = canDelete;
    }

    public String getCanReply() {
        return canReply;
    }

    public void setCanReply(String canReply) {
        this.canReply = canReply;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }


    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }


}
```

но у меня почему-то при добавлении данного метода и переменной, при попытке показать сообщение, остальные данные не грузятся, то есть без этих метода и переменной у меня есть полноценный экран показа сообщения, с темой, отправителем и самим сообщением а вот если добавить эту функцию и переменную все пропадает почему-то, это при том что я еще не отправил запрос. Может где-то не дописал 
что-то?

### UPDATE

Документация по апи:

```
URL
id - message id for view INT
attach_file_name - name of attached file

Method
GET
URL Params
type 
0 - for received messages
1 - for sent messages

Data Params
{}

Success Response
HTTP 200
Headers:
Content-Type: TYPE # file mimetype
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME # attached file name
Body: file
```

если смотреть на входящий массив то получается такая картинка:

```
"attach": [[название файла ", 0.0], ["название файла ", 0.4443359375]]
```

Если кто-то понял где именно я ошибся буду очень благодарен если укажите на мою ошибку.

Comment: Но `attach` ведь не строка, а двумерный массив. Без талмута бэкэнда нельзя сказать как его использовать, полагаю что к письму можно прикрепить несколько файлов, раз он завёрнут в массив и тут Вам нужен список, но не понятно список чего?... `private List<?> attach;`

Comment: ну массив у нас думаю потому, что у нас прикрепленный файл имеет название и размер, да `attach` это не строка, но как-то не очень понятно как вытаскивать из ответа массив который относится к сообщению, и дальше нужно как-то вытаскивать из этого массива данные которые относятся к сообщению.

Comment: Повторяю ещё раз: без документации к API сервера по этой теме помочь Вам нечем - мы понятия не имеем что за значения приходят, почему в таком формате и, соответственно, что с ними делать.

Comment: ок сейчас попробую дополнить вопрос доками)

Comment: да все таки @woesss прав)) это как-бы массив прикрепленных файлов, и каждый файл имеет две характеристики название и размер. только теперь нужно этот массив с этими двумя характеристиками вытаскивать из ответа сервера

Comment: Если возможно попросите бэкэнд сериализовать параметры файла в объект, а не массив - ибо неловко это парсить в POJO, а особенно будет беда, если параметры вдруг придут в разном порядке (Вы никак не сможете определить что где). Удобнее и надёжнее будет такой вид `"attach": [{"name":"filename.ext", "size":0.456}, {"name":"other.ext", "size":2.45}]` На нынешний вариант генератор выдаёт такой тип: `List<List<String>> attach`, то есть доставать имя нужно будет типа так: `String name = response.body().getAttach().get(0).get(0);` плюс нужно добавить проверки что всё это есть и не равно `null`.

Comment: то есть сериализация лежит полностью на бэкэнде? я думал что это я все делаю, ну в классе пишу сериалайзд)) мне если честно все еще не понятно каким образом создать функцию для того что-бы вытащить данные про этот файл так-же как и тело письма например.

Comment: короче попросил сделать сериализацию, сказали что их косяк, когда будут результаты их работы, то я создам новый вопрос, с более точной формулировкой, потому-что все-равно вопросы остались неразрешенными)) это я так понял не очень похоже на обычное вытаскивание одной переменной из ответа.