# Почему пропадает вся информация из view элементов при создании переменной android @SerializedName("переменная")?

Tags: android

Я в приложении работаю с входящими и исходящими сообщениями. Есть некоторые сообщения с прикрепленными файлами, и на данный момент я работаю над тем что-бы как-то получить эти прикрепленные файлы, то есть скачать на телефон. Для того что-бы скачать файл мне нужно знать две вещи: его наименование и id сообщения в котором он присутствует. Для показа всего сообщения у меня есть класс ViewMessage:

```
public class ViewMessage {
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("body")
    @Expose
    private String body;
    @SerializedName("can_delete")
    @Expose
    private String canDelete;
    @SerializedName("can_reply")
    @Expose
    private String canReply;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("subject")
    @Expose
    private String subject;

    @SerializedName("attach")
    private String[][] attach;

    public boolean hasAttaches() {
        return attach != null && attach.length > 0;
    }

    public String[] getAttachesNames() {
        String[] names = new String[attach.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < attach.length; i++) {
            names[i] = attach[i][0];
        }
        return names;
    }


    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /*public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }*/

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getCanDelete() {
        return canDelete;
    }

    /*public void setCanDelete(String canDelete) {
        this.canDelete = canDelete;
    }*/

    public String getCanReply() {
        return canReply;
    }

    /*public void setCanReply(String canReply) {
        this.canReply = canReply;
    }*/

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }



    /*public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }*/


}
```

как видно из кода у меня есть все необходимые функции которые вытаскивают из ответа сервера все что касается сообщения, тема, тело, отправитель и т.д. Но пока-что в этом классе нету функции которая отвечает за вытаскивание одного/нескольких наименований прикрепленных файлов. Пока-что я начал из того, что закинул функцию, что-бы потом ее вызвать в главном классе, я вставил этот кусок кода:

```
@SerializedName("attach")
    private String[][] attach;

    public boolean hasAttaches() {
        return attach != null && attach.length > 0;
    }

    public String[] getAttachesNames() {
        String[] names = new String[attach.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < attach.length; i++) {
            names[i] = attach[i][0];
        }
        return names;
    }
```

и дальше при запросе на показ сообщения, я получаю пустой экран. Если в сообщении нету прикрепленных файлов то все ок, то есть я могу увидеть тему письма на экране и все остальное, а вот если в сообщении есть прикрепленный файл, то все слетает по непонятной мне причине. Возможно я не так что-то прописал. Ранее я задавал вопрос: [Как получить прикрепленный к электронному письму файл android retrofit?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870849/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-android-retrofit)
комменты на который помогли мне структурировать полученную информацию из разнообразных источников.

### UPDATE

Закинул я короче в `onFailure()` `t.printStackTrace();` и вот какое сообщение у меня вывелось, не уверен что я скопировал то что нужен, то что я сейчас вставлю

```
08-21 09:02:07.172 W: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 219 path $.attach[0]
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
08-21 09:02:07.173 W:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:112)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 219 path $.attach[0]
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:70)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ArrayTypeAdapter.read(ArrayTypeAdapter.java:72)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
        ... 10 more
```

вот как выглядит прикрепленный файл:

```
"attach": [{"size": 0.0, "name": "\udcd0\udc9d\udcd0\udcbe\udcd0\udcb2\udcd1\udc8b\udcd0\udcb9 \udcd1\udc82\udcd0\udcb5\udcd0\udcba\udcd1\udc81\udcd1\udc82\udcd0\udcbe\udcd0\udcb2\udcd1\udc8b\udcd0\udcb9 \udcd0\udcb4\udcd0\udcbe\udcd0\udcba\udcd1\udc83\udcd0\udcbc\udcd0\udcb5\udcd0\udcbd\udcd1\udc82.txt"}, {"size": 0.4443359375, "name": "\udcd0\udc9d\udcd0\udcbe\udcd0\udcb2\udcd1\udc8b\udcd0\udcb9 \udcd1\udc82\udcd0\udcb5\udcd0\udcba\udcd1\udc81\udcd1\udc82\udcd0\udcbe\udcd0\udcb2\udcd1\udc8b\udcd0\udcb9 \udcd0\udcb4\udcd0\udcbe\udcd0\udcba\udcd1\udc83\udcd0\udcbc\udcd0\udcb5\udcd0\udcbd\udcd1\udc82 (2).txt"}]
```

Если кто-либо заметил у меня ошибку то буду очень рад если укажите мне на нее.

Comment: А что в логах ничего нет и в `onFailure` ничего не приходит? Здесь гадают по стектрейсу, а не кофейной гуще, картах и т.п.)))

Comment: Ну сообщение не крашится вроде, могу просто логи скинуть, если это поможет?)

Comment: Поможет, только сначала в `onFailure` добавьте `t.printStackTrace();`, если его у Вас там нет. Проблема не в имени однозначно - если оно не совпадает ни с одним полем в json-ответе, то просто пропускается. Скорее тип этого поля не подходит.

Comment: обновил вопрос с логами, если я скопировал то что нужно, то эта информация поможет понять мою проблему.

Comment: Дословно: мы ждали массив, а пришёл объект. У Вас же прикручен `HttpLoggingInterceptor`? Посмотрите как сейчас выглядит `attach`. Наверное бекенд уже заменил массив объектом. И теперь Вам нужно сделать класс под него и `attach` объявить как список или массив этих классов.

Comment: да поменяли на сервере, вот как теперь выглядит, "attach": [{"size": 0.0, "name": "имя "}, {"size": 0.4, "name": "имя"}], теперь я насколько @woesss понял из вашего комментария, мне нужно под классом `ViewMessage` сделать еще один класс, который будет направлен только на работу с этим массивом, и дальше этот класс объявить в классе `ViewMessage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить POJO класс, описывающий прикреплённый файл:

```
public class FileInfo {

    @SerializedName("size")
    @Expose
    private double size;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public double getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

И в классе сообщения объявить список или массив этих классов (поскольку они будут приходить в массиве):

```
@SerializedName("attach")
private List<FileInfo> attach;
```

P.S. Перепишу Ваш метод `getAttachesNames()`, может так Вам будет проще понять - Вы же как-то собирались им пользоваться:

```
public String[] getAttachesNames() {
    String[] names = new String[attach.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < attach.size(); i++) {
        FileInfo fileInfo = attach.get(i);
        names[i] = fileInfo.getName();
    }
    return names;
}
```

Comment: вот я добавил все как у Вас все написано, дальше вызываю метод `getList` и дальше вызываю этот метод в главной классе, но вот я не могу понять одну вещь - как мне например вывести названия этих файлов/одного файла, это что список делать нужно? потому-что я вот сейчас попробовал закинуть это в textView и у меня просто вывелось название пакета проекта.

Comment: Метод `getName()` даёт имя. Так же можно переопределить `toString()` и выводить что угодно и как угодно. А вот как их выводить на экран решать Вам. Можно по-разному - список, кликабельные ссылки, значки с подписями или одна кнопка/ссылка при нажатии на которую буден выведен список или сразу загрузится содержимое и добавиться текстом/картинкой, например, к письму.

Comment: ок я понял, но в целом насколько я понял Ваш способ позволяет вытащить имя и размер прикрепленного дока, и дальше уже с ним работать, но ведь метод `getName` находится совсем в другом классе, его нужно вызвать в mainActivity или в классе сообщения?

Comment: Его нужно вызвать у объекта, который лежит в списке `attach`: `List<FileInfo> attach = viewMessage.getList(); FileInfo fileInfo = attach.get(x); String name = fileInfo.getName();`. Где Вы это будете делать не важно, главное что бы там была переменная, содержащая письмо

Comment: а что вы указали как х в строке attach.get(x)?

Comment: да уже смотрю) спасибо за развернутый ответ)

Comment: а ромбы с знаками вопроса приходят из-за метода которым я тяну название или это на сервере проблемы?

Comment: На сервере - скорее всего имя неправильно закодировано

Comment: ладно я понял, поковыряюсь тогда еще немного, если что то буду новый вопрос если что. спасибо)