# Проблема с выводом названий прикрепленных к письму файлов android retrofit

Tags: android

У меня есть предыдущий вопрос: [Почему пропадает вся информация из view элементов при создании переменной android @SerializedName("переменная")?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/871018/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-view-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-androi) где благодаря пользователю @woesss и его ответу на мой вопрос мне удалось вроде-как получить название прикрепленного к письму файла. Но я столкнулся с рядом проблем которые я так и не смог решить, хотя сидел долго и перечитал все доступные мне источники информации.

Проблема заключается в том что у меня не выводит название одного прикрепленного файл. Что это означает - вот к примеру у меня к письму прикреплено два файла, и в `textView` мне показывает один рад ромбиков с знаком вопроса, а если у меня прикреплен только один файл то вообще ничего не показывает. Не могу понять в чем может быть проблема. С моего предыдущего вопроса я взял все что мне предложили, и только от себя добавил вызов функции в главном классе:

```
TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.file_name);
Button bt = findViewById(R.id.btn_download);

final String[] file_name = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAttachesNames();

for (int c = 0; c < file_name.length - 1; c++) {
txt.setText(file_name[c]);
final int finalC = c;

bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
downLoadAttachment(file_name[finalC] + "\n", key, type);}
});
}

if (file_name.length > 0) {
setEmptyBackground(bt);
} else {
bt.setEnabled(false);
txt.setText("No attachment)");
}
```

я пробую сделать так, что-бы у меня выводилось нормально название прикрепленного файла, только я вот еще не совсем додумал как сделать чтобы был вывод названий более чем одного файла, но на данный момент у меня почему-то не тянется название хотябы просто в "textView". Вероятнее всего что я что-то не учел или не дописал. Если кто заметил у меня несостыковку или ошибку, то буду очень благодарен если укажите на нее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых:
`c < file_name.length - 1` - так последний элемент (даже если он единственный) не обрабатывается уберите `- 1`
Во-вторых:
`txt.setText(file_name[c]);` - так в `TextView` заменяется весь текст на переданную строку, то есть Вы видите только то, что передано туда последним.
Чтобы добавить текст к существующему используйте

```
txt.append(file_name[c]);
```

Или собирайте весь текст `StringBuilder`'ом и потом вставляйте в `TextView` разом.