# Помогите разобраться с кастомным списком на android

Tags: android

Я у себя в приложении хочу сделать кастомный список которым я замещу простой список, в который я вывожу данные из массивов. Я нашел [такой](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial#recycling-rows) пример по созданию списка со всевозможными украшениями. Вроде все было нормально, пока я не дошел до инициализации адаптера в главном классе. В этом примере на сайте, данные которыми заполняется список уже определены заранее, и они как-бы статичны, а мне нужно что-бы список заполнялся с массивов которые определяются в процессе работы программы. Элемент списка, как структурная единица, будет состоять из двух textView и одного imageView. Вот я сделал сделал класс DataModel как было заявлено в примере:

```
public abstract class DataModel implements Collection<DataModel> {
    private String[] name;
    private Double[] size;

    protected DataModel(String[] name, Double[] size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name[0];
    }

    public Double getSize() {
        return size[0];
    }
}
```

дальше я сделал адаптер:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
    private Context mContext;

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvName, tvSize;
        ImageView ivPicture;
    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.attachment_item, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        Object object = getItem(position);
        DataModel dataModel = (DataModel) object;

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_download:
                Snackbar.make(v, "File name: " + Objects.requireNonNull(dataModel).getName(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("No action", null).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    private int lastPosition = -1;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attachment_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tvName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.tvSize = convertView.findViewById(R.id.size);
            viewHolder.ivPicture = convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_download);

            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        result.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;

        Double size = Objects.requireNonNull(dataModel).getSize();
        String size_str = size.toString();

        viewHolder.tvName.setText(dataModel.getName());
        viewHolder.tvSize.setText(size_str);
        viewHolder.ivPicture.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.ivPicture.setTag(position);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

и дальше пытаюсь сделать инициализацию списка в который будет кидаться массив названий файлов которые прикреплены к письму и их размеров:

```
final String[] file_name = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAttachesNames();
                    final Double[] file_size = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getAttachesSizes();

                    fileList = findViewById(R.id.list_attachment);
                    dataModels= new ArrayList<>();

                    dataModels.addAll(new DataModel(file_name, file_size) {
                        @Override
                        public boolean addAll(@NonNull Collection<? extends DataModel> collection) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

но мне предлагает студия наследовать все методы из `DataModel`:
[image: описание скриншота].

И вот собственно я не могу понять, как мне избавится от этого предложения, или все-таки нужно сделать implement всех методов которые там есть?

Заранее спасибо за ценные советы.

Comment: А зачем вам свой тип коллекции?

Comment: не очень понял если честно ваш вопрос, что такое колекция, вы спрашиваете зачем мне кастомный `listView`?

Comment: Вы класс `DataModel` неправильно сделали. Он ни от чего не должен наследоваться и в нем не должно быть массивов. Он представляет ОДИН элемент данных

Comment: то есть нужно его сделать так-же как и в примере? а где тогда будет массив?

Comment: Представьте себе стопку тетрадей. Вот вы и создаете класс для тетради. У каждой тетради должны быть свойства - цвет, количество листов и т.д. Вы внутри класса создаете int sheetCount, color. А конкретно массив (или коллекция) этих тетрадей будет уже в активности/фрагменте/еще где-то

Comment: то есть согласно вашему примеру, мой класс `DataModel` представляет свойства файла, а уже массив этих свойств будет инициализироваться уже в главном классе?

Comment: Да, только массив не свойств, а объектов `DataModel`.

Comment: @Flippy прав, вот это `class DataModel implements Collection<DataModel>` никуда не годится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш класс, отвечающий за данные элемента списка неверен. Надо так:

```
public class DataModel {
    private String name;
    private double size;

    public DataModel(String name, double size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Затем полученные массивы надо разбить по классам-моделям:

```
List<DataModel> data = new ArrayList<>():
for (int i = 0; i < file_name.length; i++) {
    data.add(new DataModel(file_name[i], file_size[i]));
}
```

Comment: Не очень понимаю как разбить полученные массивы по классам моделям. Это нужно делать в главном классе?

Comment: @Andrew Goroshko, да, сразу после того как получаете эти массивы. Вам приходят 2 массива. Вам надо из каждого по очереди вынимать данные и создавать экземпляр `DataModel`. Кстати странный API. Вы уверены, что данные именно в таком виде получаете?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, просто замените `DataModel` на `FileInfo` из моего ответа  (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/871262/11515) и отдавайте адаптеру сразу список `attach` без дополнительных манипуляций.

Comment: @woesss, просто - не значит полезно для ТС

Comment: @Flippy, дело в том что ТС получает готовый список с сервера (Retrofit + Gson), достаёт из него имена и размеры в массивы, а теперь из массивов собирает обратно модель (сравните Ваш класс и мой) - как считаете, не лишняя работа?

Comment: @woesss, я понял, что это ретрофит. И я знаю про gson. Но для ТС считаю хорошо бы было разобраться в том как они работают.

Comment: @Flippy, я обращался не к Вам и не утверждал, что Ваш ответ неверный или не полезный. Я посоветовал ТС как сделать проще, основываясь на том, что известно из его прошлых вопросов.

Comment: @woesss, а.. Понял, простите

Comment: @Flippy я если честно пока-что только начал читать ответы, я не понял кто или что такое TC? что это означает?)

Comment: ТС - топик стартер - спрашивающий, Вы.

Comment: ок я понял)) я просто в такой терминологии не очень силен) вроде все нормально выводится в listView,немного допилить сам вывод нужно, спасибо что помогли.

Comment: @Andrew Goroshko, рад был помочь)